# How to break up array at specific point in Ruby? And leave all remaining items

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have arrays like this:

```
myArr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
myArr = [a]
myArr = [a,b,c]
```

**How can I break up the arrays such that:**

Variable `first_portion` has the **first 3 items** and `rest_portion` **has all remaining ones**?

If an array has 3 or less items, I'd like rest_portion to contain nil so that I can check for it in logic.

**Any advise?**

Comment: I'd suggest that testing for `rest_portion.empty?` is as good as `rest_portion.nil?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a range for the array index to accomplish this easily:

```
first_portion = myArr[0..2]
rest_portion = myArr[3..-1]
```

If the range partially overlaps the range, you'll get an array with only as many items as are available. If the range has no overlap with the array, you'll get nil.

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g][0..2]
#=> [a, b, c]
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g][3..-1]
#=> [d,e,f,g]

[a][0..2]
#=> [a]
[a][3..-1]
#=> nil
```

Comment: +1, although it looks better if the number in the code is the number in the formulation of the problem. So: `xs[0...3]` or `xs[0, 3]`.

Answer (score 6):

Look at [Array#shift](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift)

```
>>  myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>> firstPart = myArr.shift(3)
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> firstPart
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> myArr
=> [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Fails the explicit condition from the OP: _"I'd like rest_portion to contain `nil`"_

Comment: Checking for it can easily be done with `myArr.empty?` instead of looking for nil.  Don't throw out an elegant solution due to a bad constraint, if you can change the constraint. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>> myArr = %w|a b c d e f g|
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
>> first_portion, rest_portion = myArr[0, 3], myArr[3..-1].nil? ? nil : myArr[3..-1].empty? ? nil : myArr[3..-1]
=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f", "g"]]

>> first_portion
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> rest_portion
=> ["d", "e", "f", "g"]


>> myArr = %w|a|
=> ["a"]
>> first_portion, rest_portion = myArr[0, 3], myArr[3..-1].nil? ? nil : myArr[3..-1].empty? ? nil : myArr[3..-1]
=> [["a"], nil]

>> first_portion
=> ["a"]
>> rest_portion
=> nil

>> myArr = %w|a b c|=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> first_portion, rest_portion = myArr[0, 3], myArr[3..-1].nil? ? nil : myArr[3..-1].empty? ? nil : myArr[3..-1]
=> [["a", "b", "c"], nil]

>> first_portion
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> rest_portion
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
first_portion = myArr[0,3]
rest_portion = myArr[3, myArr.length-3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
first_portion, last_portion = myArr[0..2], myArr[3..-1]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]

myArr = [1]
first_portion, last_portion = myArr[0..2], myArr[3..-1]
=> [[1, 2, 3], nil]

myArr = [1,2,3]
first_portion, last_portion = myArr[0..2], myArr[3..-1]
=> [[1, 2, 3], []]
```

Comment: Double-checking all the offered answers; I've pretty much duped what Daniel's posted - just without the ternary to check for an empty last_portion :-/